# ¿ Como crear una tabla de contenido dinámica en documento dompdf con numero de pagina?

Tags: php, pdf, symfony, dompdf

Estoy creando un manual dompdf, la información lo voy a llenar desde base de datos, pero necesito crear el índice o tabla de contenido que contenga el título y la página donde se encuentra.

Hasta el momento he podido traer el título con:

preg_match_all('/<h([1-6])[^>]*>(.*?)</h\1>/', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$index = "";

```
foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
            $level = $match[1];
            $title = strip_tags($match[2]);
            $titlef = str_replace(":", " ", $title);
            $page = $dompdf->getCanvas()->get_page_number($titlef);
            $cantCaracter = 130;

            $longitudActual = strlen($titlef);

            if ($longitudActual < $cantCaracter) {
                $cantidadFaltante = $cantCaracter - $longitudActual;
                $titlef .= str_repeat("-", $cantidadFaltante);
            }
            
            if ($key === count($matches) - 1) {
                if ($level == 5) {
                    $index .= "$titlef";
                }else{
                    $index .= "   "."$titlef";
                }
            }else{
                if ($level == 5) {
                    $index .= "$titlef//";
                }else{
                    $index .= "   "."$titlef//";
                }
            }
        }
```

pero no puedo traer en que página encuentra el título,
al hacer esto $page = $dompdf->getCanvas()->get_page_number($titlef); me trae solo el total de páginas, no la página donde se encuentra el título

Comment: El idioma del sitio es el Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta y no olvides agregar lo que has intentado para resolver tu preoblema. ;)

Comment: Recuerda agregar mayor información a tu pregunta para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar de mejor forma. Te sugerimos revisar el documento [ask]. saludos.